# Kaal Bhairav idol vs Hanuman idol in Goddess temples

Tags: temple, hanuman, goddess, bhairava

I have seen that at some temples especially of Mother Paravati, there are statues of Kaal Bhairav whereas in others there are statues of Hanumanji. Why is this difference?

Is it because the shakti peethas are protected by Kaalbhairav at those sites which are from the time Hanumanji was not born so they are more ancient?

Comment: It's because Lord Shiva assigned each Bhairav for protection of each Shakti peeth... I think Kal Bhairav was appointed near Kashi area...